# The json key is not being omitted where the cells are empty in examples of Scenario Outline .What change needs to be done?

Tags: karate

The following is the scenario Outline i have used . In the first and second row the display_name is empty but still display_name is being sent in my request payload .

```
Scenario Outline: Negative cases

  Given path '/api/check'
  And request {name: <name> , description: <description> , display_name: <display_name>}
  When method POST
  Then status <status>
```

Examples:

```
| name     |   description    |    display_name              |status  | 
|""        |     "sasadss"    |                              | 400    |                                     
|"fddsd"   |      ""          |                              | 400    |
| "ccs"    |       ""         |      "disp "                 | 400    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuately Cucumber `Example` tables send an empty string. You can use `table` as an alternative or you can put the whole JSON into a column, many teams do this.

```
| value            |
| { some: 'json' } |
```

Refer to this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature

Comment: Thanks .. Actually at first I gave the whole JSON into a column but when i tried to run it from terminal , I got an error saying "Multiple build operations failed .Could not write XML test results for | { name: '', description:'sasadss'} | " . but all the test cases passed in surefire-reports.  @peter